# StyleCop Madness: protected field

Tags: c#, inheritance, protected, stylecop

I was commisioned to make other people's code compliant with some StyleCop ruleset, as far as possible.. now I was wondering about the following case:

I have an abstract class that contains a field

```
protected double[] coefficients;
```

Stylecop says: *SA1401: Fields must be declared with private access. Use properties to expose fields.*

So I changed it to:

```
protected double[] coefficients { get; set; }
```

Stylecop says: *SA1300: property names begin with an upper-case letter: coefficients.*

Since it's an abstract class, the child classes are beyond my control. And they use their parent's class field `base.coefficients`.. well.

So.. there is no way other way to get rid of this warning than to suppress (or disable) it, right? :T

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, actually you don't.

If you want to get it clean in future releases of the code, you could set the `coefficients` property deprecated and provide a message that states that this property will be removed in any further version of the code.

In the current release:

```
private double[] _coefficients;

// Using this property will produce a compile-time warning.
[Obsolete("coefficients will be removed in future versions. Use Coefficients instead.")]
protected double[] coefficients 
{ 
    get { return _coefficients; } 
    set { _coefficients = value; } 
}

protected double[] Coefficients 
{ 
    get { return _coefficients; } 
    set { _coefficients = value; } 
}
```

In a later release:

```
private double[] _coefficients;

// Using this property will produce a compile-time error.
[Obsolete("coefficients was removed. Use Coefficients instead.", true)]
protected double[] coefficients 
{ 
    get { return _coefficients; } 
    set { _coefficients = value; } 
}

protected double[] Coefficients 
{ 
    get { return _coefficients; } 
    set { _coefficients = value; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... although after the other guys' comments, I'm probably going to just suppress the warning and be done with it. ;)

Comment: Yes, of course my answer only applies if you really need to have this fixed :)

Comment: This code though will run you straight into an FxCop violation since you have members which differ only by case :)

Comment: Fix one, get one. At least it's balanced :)

Answer (score 5):

Even changing fields to properties is a potentially breaking change. If you have to retain compatibility with compiled binaries that you have no control over, I don't even recommend making the *first* change.

The thing you have to remember about StyleCop is that it doggedly insists that you follow coding ***guidelines***, which are not really the same thing as rules. Both of the guidelines you've run into are perfectly reasonable. I always follow them when writing new code. You should, too. However, if, as in your case, compatibility is more important, then it's probably permissible  to ignore StyleCop's insistence.

Even if you were to solve the current warning, the next thing it'll probably hit you with (or if it doesn't, it [*should*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx), and FxCop definitely does catch this) is that arrays should never be exposed as part of an interface (meaning, marked `protected` or `public`). Instead, you should expose something like `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Rinse, lather, repeat. You're just chasing your tail if you can't really change the code.

And just to see if I can drive you even more insane, I'll note that FxCop would throw a fit if it were to discover that the child classes were explicitly calling a member on their parent class if they don't override the implementation of that member themselves. So basically, `base.coefficients` is no-no in the first place. If you follow *all* the guidelines, it makes following them easier. The logical corollary, of course, is that if you *don't* follow all of the guidelines, it makes following them much more difficult.

Comment: The practical viewpoint is very much appreciated.  It is good to put guidelines in perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you change field to property, the derived classes (from other compiled assemblies) will not find "coefficients", because property is shortcut for two methods - not equals with field.

If you must hold compatibility with other assemblies, the compatibility must be primary and StyleCop rules secondary goal.

Comment: yes. well, so far i have usually been able to tell whether it is possible to change something in order to make it compliant. for example spacing, private variables etc. - i just was not sure whether i'm declaring this case "unsolvable" too quickly.

Comment: hmmm... can you elaborate more on that? Florian's solution seems to work with my unit tests.

Comment: If you recompile unit tests with edited source code, there is no problem. The problem with changeing filed->property is only, if depending code is already compiled and can not be recompiled.